# How do I work around cases where the listProvider data comes back as just ONE single record?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.6, flash-builder4.5

Im using HTTPservice to load XML and show the results in a list - it works when there are more than 1 XML record found.... but when there is only ONE single returned XML record it gets treated differently for some reason and generates this error:

```
Suspended: TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert mx.utils::ObjectProxy
```

I see posts like this:

```
http://anupushkaran.blogspot.com/2010/02/typeerror-error-1034-type-coercion.html
```

but I cant figure out how to adapt it to my HTTPService resultHandler code block...

Im using FB 4.6 and my XML structure looks like the following:

```
SiteXYZ
   Events
      EventListing
```

and all the data I want to use is under the EventListing Node.

I've tested some code that can detect when the length of whats returned so I think I can just detect when the length is 1 and then handle something differently -- not sure what though.

Another thing Im seeing that I think gets me close...   when I look at the network monitor's TreeView > Response > Response Body I can see that on a succesful trip, the body comes back like:

```
SiteXYZ
  Events
     EventListing
        [0]
        [1]....  and so on....
```

But on the cases where its a SINGLE record returned, the body of the response comes back like:

```
SiteXYZ
   Events
      EventListing
```

so shouldnt I be able to detect when its just ONE returned record and then set the list dataProvider accordingly?  so that when its a lot of returned records the dataprovider is set with:

```
list1.dataProvider = myXML.lastResult.SiteXYZ.Events.EventListing;
```

but when its just ONE returned record, how would that dataProvider be set?  this didnt work:

```
list1.dataProvider = lfXML.lastResult.LeisureFun.Events;
```

can anyone help with this?  is my approach way off base?  sorry for the rambling nature of the question but as I typed it, I stopped about 5 times and tried a number of things that came to mind as I thought through it... still nothing worked though... I feel like Im onto something (could be wrong though) but just cant solve it yet.

Comment: I ran into this about 2 years ago with flex 3 And I do not remember what I did. But I am thinking i had to make a custom item renderer for it. I can look at the code in a few hours

Comment: @The_asMan - thanks.  i appreciate it. Im to the point where Im basically thinking about padding my xml with an extra fake record and then set some type of flag to try to supress / hide it AFTER the list is built... sad and I probably wont do this - but I gave it some serious thought!

Comment: It looks to me, from the description that in the first situation you're returning an array.  In the second situation are aren't returning an array.  That seems unusual to me.  Why wouldn't the second situation return an array with a single element?  Like: EventListing [0].  Correcting the inconsistent structure should solve the problem.

Comment: exactly... thats my whole thing. I'd expect it to just do the same thing and return data as expected- but this whole thing of it returning differently when a single record is really bothering me. heres the explanation I saw explained on the website/url i referenced in the original post: "While we are accessing data from server in most cases the result is return as an ArrayCollection. But there is a chance that it may reach the client as ObjectProxy. For example if we are reading an XML file only having zero or one tag , it will not return the result as ArrayCollection rather as ObjectProxy."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was in the original website  I referenced....

i took a closer look at what that post said the problem presented was and how that code snippet addressed it and was able to get it to work for me by putting it in my resultHandler block...

```
arr=new ArrayCollection();
if(event.result.SiteXYZ.Events.EventListing is ArrayCollection)
{
arr = ArrayCollection(event.result.SiteXYZ.Events.EventListing);
}
if(event.result.SiteXYZ.Events.EventListing is ObjectProxy)
{
arr =new ArrayCollection(ArrayUtil.toArray
    (event.result.SiteXYZ.Events.EventListing));
}
```

now when there is one record returned it shows fine... same for multiple records returned.

thanks for the help though... I'll definately save this snippet for future use!